# Change trace file in H2

Tags: h2

My application uses H2 but already has a log file (ex: abc.log)

Now, I'm trying to make even the H2 to write logs/errors to that file (abc.log) so if something goes wrong an user has only 1 file to send to me (not abc.log AND abc.db.trace file)

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the solution was to simple for me to believe it but the only thing I had to do is to add

```
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
```

and

```
slf4j-jdk14-1.7.2.jar
```

in my app's classpath.

As SLF4J will (first search and then) discover by itself what underlying logging framework to use it is simply a matter of placing the right implementation.

One warning, it seems that SLF4J can not use more than one frameworks at a time so this solution work **ONLY** if you have a single existing framework.

Answer (score 5):

You can [configure H2 to use SL4FJ](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#other_logging) as follows:

```
jdbc:h2:~/test;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4
```

The logger name is `h2database`.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. Can you give more info of how to proceed. As far as I see I do need to use sl4fs and search for that h2database logger (with LoggerFactory.getLogger('h2database '))...but from there? Thanks

Comment: That's it, you just use SLF4J configure a logger for "h2database". For more information about SLF4J, see the SLF4J web site.

Comment: I do see now that a new folder is create [trace.db] in app's folder. How can I remove/disable it?

Comment: And you did append `;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4` to the database URL? What is your database URL?

Comment: I do use different connection URLs, one for development and one for development 

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4", "sa", "");` and one for release `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:" + f.getCanonicalPath() + ";TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4", "sa", "");`

Comment: You are right, I can reproduce it. This is a bug, I will fix it in the next release of H2. So I'm afraid there is no simple solution when using the server mode.

Comment: I use server mode only for development (to be able to open many connection) as for production I use embedded version.